# XML RPC post request with cURL (PHP) not working

Tags: php, curl, xml-rpc

I want to add records to zoho creator using the XML RPC api (http://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/xml-rpc-api/xml-rpc-api-add-records.html) with cURL (PHP).
The code I'm using is:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'] )) {
    // if data is posted
    $urltopost = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/write"; 
    $xml = '<ZohoCreator>
    <applicationlist>
        <application name=\'myapp\'>
            <formlist>
                <form name=\'my form\'>
                    <add>
                        <field name=\'fieldName\'>
                           <value>value</value>
                        </field>
                    </add>
                </form>
            </formlist>
        </application>
    </applicationlist>
</ZohoCreator>';

$datatopost = array (
'authtoken' => '*******', //my authtoken
'scope' => 'creatorapi',
'XMLString' => $xml ,
'zc_ownername' => '*****'//the owner name
);
// post via curl
$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
?>
```

But this doesn't work. Does any one have a solution? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `http_build_query()` over the `$datatopost`, otherwise its posted as `multipart/form-data`

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($datatopost));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did what you said but doesn't solve the problem. I did: echo "Returned data<br><xmp>{$returndata}</xmp>"; but it just displayed Returned data!! doesn't seem that the request is sent.